# "this" keyword doesn't return Context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I defined my own Custom `ArrayAdapter`, named `WordAdapter`, like this:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
Context context;

public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    TextView miwok = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
    miwok.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());

    TextView english = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.english_text_view);
    english.setText(currentWord.getEnglishTranslation());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

I need it in a class and it is used like this:

```
public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add(new Word("lutti","one"));
    words.add(new Word("otiiko","two"));
    words.add(new Word("toldokosu","three"));
    words.add(new Word("oyyisa","four"));
    words.add(new Word("massoka","five"));
    words.add(new Word("temmoka","six"));
    words.add(new Word("kenekaku","seven"));
    words.add(new Word("kawinta","eight"));
    words.add(new Word("wo'e","nine"));
    words.add(new Word("na'aacha","ten"));

    WordAdapter itemsAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


    }
}
```

But it gives error in the line `WordAdapter itemsAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);`, saying

> WordAdapter (android.content.Context   ArrayList) cannot be applied to com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity    ArrayList

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: You probably need to pass something like `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.

Comment: Pass `NumberActivity.this` in adapter

Comment: @KrishnaJ: How is `NumbersActivity.this` different from `this`?

Comment: Post your `WordAdapter` code.

Comment: `this` or `getApplicationContext` may not work sometimes and in some device but this pass correct reference of activity.

Comment: KrishnaJ tried it, same error. @Thilo, it says Cant resolve method

Comment: There's no need to store a `Context` field inside a custom `ArrayAdapter` class anyway, as there is already a [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getContext()) method

Comment: @MarkKeen done, please check

Comment: MainActivty.this and this is the same in, pardon the pun, 'this' case

Comment: @PPartisan I am going to use context to know which Activity the request comes from, as I have many activity similar to NumbersActivity, which is having similar errors

Comment: I dont think in your case this is not a Context .try restart your AndroidStudio

Comment: As I restarted Android Studio, It doesn't even open the project saying "NullPointerException". I think this had to do something with the update to AndroidStudio I did earlier today

Comment: Guys I updated Android Studio and it works now. But the same error occurs. Please help

Comment: Can you add your dependencies too ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto sure check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell there is no problem in your code. `AppCompatActivity` is `Context` itself. So, passing `"this"` should work anyway.

So as I can see, there is dependency conflict. If you have added appcompat dependency, you don't have to add `support V4` dependency too, because `supportv4` package comes with `appcompat` dependency already.

What would I suggest is to remove `support v4` dependency and sync with gradle again. it should be fine then,
Even though if it does not work, just do one more step ie.
Click on `File -> Invalidate/Cache Restart -> Click on Invalidate cahe and Restart.`

Now I am pretty much sure, that problem will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

When refereincing purely `this` it may reffer to the type of method it is inside. I have seen issues with it myself, especially in onCreate.

That means `this` does not reffer to context, it might some times reffer to the class, sometimes it reffers runnable, in my experience it varies. YOu can either try `YourClass.this` where YourClass is an `Activity` extending class(any activity, even AppCompatActivity). In your case, `YourClass` is `NumbersActivity`.

Alternativly, you can use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()`

Comment: I tried NumbersActivity.this. Produces the same error. It produces Cant resolve method error for getApplicationContext(). I think it has to do something with the update in Android Studio I did earlier today

Comment: could it have something to do with you using AppCompatActivity? Did you try getBaseContext()? Did you try to write super.get...Context

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: 2.1.2. It was working before the update. Now I have restarted AndroidStudio and cant even open projects. It says "Cant load: java.lang.NullPointerException"